# SQLite can't find a way to avoid Cartesian Product

Tags: sql, sqlite, cartesian-product

I'm writing a query where I'm calculating sums of 2 different tables, which have a foreign key constraint (1:n).

[image]

So there's the table `Kunde` which is holding Customers. Every `Customer` is maintained by a `Adm`. Every `Kunde` has N different transactions (`PbsRow`), while every transaction contains N different products (`WarengruppeVK`). Every transaction has a Month and a Year (`Monat` and `Jahr`)

What I need is a result which contains the following information:
1) Name of an Adm, 2) Sum of all `sollfracht` and `handling` values which belong to one of the customers of this particular Adm in 2013, 3) Sum of all `netto` and `db_basis` values which belong to one of the `PbsRow`s of that customer in 2013, 4 & 5) Same as 2) & 3) just in 2012

I have already tried different things, but I always end up having a Cartesian product with the `sollfracht` and `handling` values when I do the Join with the next Table.

Please have a look at my query:

```
SELECT vj.*,
       j.*,
       adm.ZNAME
FROM ZADM adm,
  (SELECT k.ZADMITARBEITER AS admidvj,
          SUM(vk.ZNETTO) AS summeVJ,
          SUM(vk.ZDB_BASIS) AS summeDBVJ,
          SUM(p.ZSOLLFRACHT) AS sollfrachtVJ,
          SUM(p.ZHANDLING) AS handlingVJ
   FROM ZWARENGRUPPEVK vk
   LEFT JOIN ZPBSROW p ON p.Z_PK=vk.ZPBSROW
   LEFT JOIN ZKUNDE k ON k.Z_PK=p.ZKUNDE
   WHERE ZJAHR=2012
     AND ZMONAT>=1
     AND ZMONAT<=6
   GROUP BY k.ZADMITARBEITER) vj,
  (SELECT k.ZADMITARBEITER AS admidj,
          SUM(vk.ZNETTO) AS summeJ,
          SUM(vk.ZDB_BASIS) AS summeDBJ,
          SUM(p.ZSOLLFRACHT) AS sollfrachtJ,
          SUM(p.ZHANDLING) AS handlingJ
   FROM ZWARENGRUPPEVK vk
   LEFT JOIN ZPBSROW p ON p.Z_PK=vk.ZPBSROW
   LEFT JOIN ZKUNDE k ON k.Z_PK=p.ZKUNDE
   WHERE ZJAHR=2013
     AND ZMONAT>=1
     AND ZMONAT<=6
   GROUP BY k.ZADMITARBEITER) j
WHERE vj.admidvj=j.admidj
  AND vj.admidvj=adm.Z_PK
```

What can I do to avoid having this cartesian product? When I remove the `WarengruppeVK`-table from the result, the `sollfracht` and `handling` values are correct.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: 
Here are some samples.

This is the result I'm getting from the query above:
[image]

And here's the result when I remove the very first join:
[image]

You'll notice that `sollfrachtVJ` and `handlingVJ` are different now. They are taken from `PbsRow` where the cartesian product happens. So these 2 values are actually the correct ones, but I also need the sums of the 2 values I have commented out.

And this here is the SQL statement after I have removed that one Join:

```
SELECT vj.*,
       j.*,
       adm.ZNAME
FROM ZADM adm,
  (SELECT k.ZADMITARBEITER AS admidvj,
          --          SUM(vk.ZNETTO) AS summeVJ,
--          SUM(vk.ZDB_BASIS) AS summeDBVJ,

          SUM(p.ZSOLLFRACHT) AS sollfrachtVJ,
          SUM(p.ZHANDLING) AS handlingVJ
   FROM -- ZWARENGRUPPEVK vk
 ZPBSROW p -- LEFT JOIN ZPBSROW p ON p.Z_PK=vk.ZPBSROW

   LEFT JOIN ZKUNDE k ON k.Z_PK=p.ZKUNDE
   WHERE ZJAHR=2012
     AND ZMONAT>=1
     AND ZMONAT<=6
   GROUP BY k.ZADMITARBEITER) vj,
  (SELECT k.ZADMITARBEITER AS admidj,
          SUM(vk.ZNETTO) AS summeJ,
          SUM(vk.ZDB_BASIS) AS summeDBJ,
          SUM(p.ZSOLLFRACHT) AS sollfrachtJ,
          SUM(p.ZHANDLING) AS handlingJ
   FROM ZWARENGRUPPEVK vk
   LEFT JOIN ZPBSROW p ON p.Z_PK=vk.ZPBSROW
   LEFT JOIN ZKUNDE k ON k.Z_PK=p.ZKUNDE
   WHERE ZJAHR=2013
     AND ZMONAT>=1
     AND ZMONAT<=6
   GROUP BY k.ZADMITARBEITER) j
WHERE vj.admidvj=j.admidj
  AND vj.admidvj=adm.Z_PK
```

**EDIT 2**

Ok, here's the SQL statement which contains the correct result, but misses 4 columns.

```
SELECT vj.*,
       j.*,
       adm.ZNAME
FROM ZADM adm,
  (SELECT k.ZADMITARBEITER AS admidvj,
          SUM(p.ZSOLLFRACHT) AS sollfrachtVJ,
          SUM(p.ZHANDLING) AS handlingVJ
   FROM ZPBSROW p
   LEFT JOIN ZKUNDE k ON k.Z_PK=p.ZKUNDE
   WHERE ZJAHR=2012
     AND ZMONAT>=1
     AND ZMONAT<=6
   GROUP BY k.ZADMITARBEITER) vj,
  (SELECT k.ZADMITARBEITER AS admidj,
          SUM(p.ZSOLLFRACHT) AS sollfrachtJ,
          SUM(p.ZHANDLING) AS handlingJ
   FROM ZPBSROW p
   LEFT JOIN ZKUNDE k ON k.Z_PK=p.ZKUNDE
   WHERE ZJAHR=2013
     AND ZMONAT>=1
     AND ZMONAT<=6
   GROUP BY k.ZADMITARBEITER) j
WHERE vj.admidvj=j.admidj
  AND vj.admidvj=adm.Z_PK
```

As you can see, `summeJ`, `summeVJ`, `summeDBJ` and `summeDBVJ` are not included, that's where the problem is. All values in this result are correct, but I also need to have these 4 values in my result. The first screenshot of my results above contain correct `summeJ`, `summeVJ`, `summeDBJ` and `summeDBVJ` values, but incorrect `handlingJ`, `handlingVJ`, `sollfrachtJ` and `sollfrachtVJ` values.

**EDIT 3:**

I finally found a way to do this. Here's the query that works. It's just a couple of subqueries:

```
    SELECT ((summeJ-summeVJ)/summeVJ*100) AS abwNetto,
       (summeJ-summeVJ) AS abwNettoAbs,
       ((summeDBJ-summeDBVJ)/summeDBVJ*100) AS abwDB,
       (summeDBJ-summeDBVJ) AS abwDBAbs,
       t0.*,
       t1.*,
       adm.ZNAME
FROM ZADM adm,
  (SELECT vj.*,
          j.*
   FROM
     (SELECT k.ZADMITARBEITER AS admidvj,
             SUM(p.ZSOLLFRACHT) AS sollfrachtVJ,
             SUM(p.ZHANDLING) AS handlingVJ
      FROM ZPBSROW p
      LEFT JOIN ZKUNDE k ON k.Z_PK=p.ZKUNDE
      WHERE ZJAHR=2012
        AND ZMONAT>=1
        AND ZMONAT<=6
      GROUP BY k.ZADMITARBEITER) vj
   LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT k.ZADMITARBEITER AS admidj,
             SUM(p.ZSOLLFRACHT) AS sollfrachtJ,
             SUM(p.ZHANDLING) AS handlingJ
      FROM ZPBSROW p
      LEFT JOIN ZKUNDE k ON k.Z_PK=p.ZKUNDE
      WHERE ZJAHR=2013
        AND ZMONAT>=1
        AND ZMONAT<=6
      GROUP BY k.ZADMITARBEITER) j ON vj.admidvj = j.admidj) t0,
  (SELECT vj.*,
          j.*
   FROM
     (SELECT k.ZADMITARBEITER AS admidvj,
             SUM(vk.ZNETTO) AS summeVJ,
             SUM(vk.ZDB_BASIS) AS summeDBVJ
      FROM ZPBSROW p
      LEFT JOIN ZWARENGRUPPEVK vk ON vk.ZPBSROW=p.Z_PK
      LEFT JOIN ZKUNDE k ON k.Z_PK=p.ZKUNDE
      WHERE ZJAHR=2012
        AND ZMONAT>=1
        AND ZMONAT<=6
      GROUP BY k.ZADMITARBEITER) vj
   LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT k.ZADMITARBEITER AS admidj,
             SUM(vk.ZNETTO) AS summeJ,
             SUM(vk.ZDB_BASIS) AS summeDBJ
      FROM ZPBSROW p
      LEFT JOIN ZWARENGRUPPEVK vk ON vk.ZPBSROW=p.Z_PK
      LEFT JOIN ZKUNDE k ON k.Z_PK=p.ZKUNDE
      WHERE ZJAHR=2013
        AND ZMONAT>=1
        AND ZMONAT<=6
      GROUP BY k.ZADMITARBEITER) j ON vj.admidvj = j.admidj) t1
WHERE t0.admidvj=t1.admidvj
  AND t0.admidvj=adm.Z_PK
```

[image]

Comment: Please show a few example records and the expected result.

Comment: I have added some sample records :-). Thx

Comment: You say these results are wrong. Please show some *correct* results that you actually want, and the source records they are computed from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your joins is that everything is joined together.
You should use independent scalar subqueries instead:

```
SELECT name,
       (SELECT SUM(WarengruppeVK.netto)
        FROM Kunde
        JOIN PbsRow ON Kunde.PK = PbsRow.kunde
        JOIN WarengruppeVK ON PbsRow.PK = WarengruppeVK.pbsrow
        WHERE Kunde.admitarbeiter = Adm.PK
          AND PbsRow.jahr = 2012
       ) AS vj_netto,
       (SELECT SUM(PbsRow.sollfracht)
        FROM Kunde
        JOIN PbsRow ON Kunde.PK = PbsRow.kunde
        WHERE Kunde.admitarbeiter = Adm.PK
          AND PbsRow.jahr = 2012
       ) AS vj_sollfracht
       (SELECT SUM(WarengruppeVK.netto)
        FROM Kunde
        JOIN PbsRow ON Kunde.PK = PbsRow.kunde
        JOIN WarengruppeVK ON PbsRow.PK = WarengruppeVK.pbsrow
        WHERE Kunde.admitarbeiter = Adm.PK
          AND PbsRow.jahr = 2013
       ) AS j_netto,
       (SELECT SUM(PbsRow.sollfracht)
        FROM Kunde
        JOIN PbsRow ON Kunde.PK = PbsRow.kunde
        WHERE Kunde.admitarbeiter = Adm.PK
          AND PbsRow.jahr = 2013
       ) AS j_sollfracht
FROM Adm
```

Comment: Yes, I have figured that out too and was wondering if there was some other solution than separating the queries. Thanks for your answer.